# change a json value with a Python 3.8 script

Tags: python, json, autokey

I want change one json value with a Python 3.8 script.

I know in Python, strings are immutable, so you can't change their characters in-place.

This helps my much: [How to find and replace a part of a value in json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53077503/how-to-find-and-replace-a-part-of-a-value-in-json-file)

#### TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

> `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`
> item['hotKey'] = ""
> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

#### Script: `item['hotKey'] = "<f11>"`

```
from pathlib import Path
import json
home = str(Path.home())
path = home + "/.config/autokey/data/Sample Scripts/"
jsonFilePath = home + "/.config/autokey/data/Sample Scripts/.run-run-lintalistAHK-all.json"
with open(jsonFilePath) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
for item in data['hotkey']:
    item['hotKey'] = "<f11>"  # item['hotKey'].replace('$home', item['id'])
with open(jsonFilePath, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

**json file**

```
{
     "hotkey": {
         "hotKey": "<f12>"
     },
}
```

Comment: You just want `data["hotKey"]["hotKey"] = "<f11>"`, no need to loop.

Comment: You never change a string. You assign a new string, a literal, or built in some way.

Comment: I made a typo. It should be data["hotkey"]["hotKey"] = "<f11>"

Comment: btw Your `item` variable is, in turn, each of the keys (ie a string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `json['hotkey']` reference before:

```
for item in data['hotkey']:
    data['hotkey'][item] = "<f11>"  # item['hotKey'].replace('$home', item['id'])
```

My raw attempt:

```
import json
j = '''
{
     "hotkey": {
         "hotKey": "<f12>"
     }
}
'''
data = json.loads(j)
for x in data['hotkey']:
  data['hotkey'][x] = '<f11>'
print(data)
```

Comment: This is OK, but (again) I doubt he really wants to change all the hotkeys to the same key.

Comment: Upvoting assuming this is just for example.

Comment: Both snippets change all the values to `"<f11>"` regardless of what the keys are.

Comment: @quamrana my solution change only one value and its works: https://i.imgur.com/4K5qkVv.png

Comment: Yes, thats right, because you have used the solution from @progmatico and not the looping code in this answer.