# Change values in a kivy storage

Tags: python, kivy, storage

Can someone tell me how to change a value in a kivy storage (JsonStore) ?
Here is an example of what I have :

```
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore

store = JsonStore("Test.json")

store["MyDict"] = {"0":"H", "1":"A", "2":"Y"}
print(store["MyDict"])

store["MyDict"]["1"] = "E"
print(store["MyDict"])
```

This code work but when I look in the `Test.json` file, there is this **dictionnary {"0":"H", "1":"A", "2":"Y"}** instead of this one **{"0":"H", "1":"E", "2":"Y"}**

I would like to use this as a normal dictionary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find and replace a part of a value in json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53077503/how-to-find-and-replace-a-part-of-a-value-in-json-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot directly do this because that store object is not a dictionary.
however, you can store your whole dictionary as one item in the store.
In this example, entry is a Python dict.  According to the kivy.storage documentation, the storage objects have put(), get(), exists(), delete() and find() methods.  This code shows a printout of protected memeber _data of the object which is a dict but it should not be modified directly.

```
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore

store = JsonStore("Test.json")

MyDict = {"0": "H", "1": "A", "2": "Y"}
store.put("settings", MyDict=MyDict)

entry = store.get('settings')['MyDict']
entry["1"] = "E"
store.put("settings", MyDict=MyDict)
entry = store.get('settings')['MyDict']
print(f"protected member {store._data}")
print(entry["1"])
```